# Simple charitable upload bandwidth donation w/o legal worries?

Tags: bittorrent, bandwidth

My ISP plan includes 100Mbit/s uncapped upload that is mostly unused. Help me donate it to a charitable cause in a way that meets these conditions:

1. no risk of legal hassles (i.e. illegal P2P seeding is out)
2. minimal manual work apart from the first setup (i.e. having to manually add new Linux isos in Bittorrent is suboptimal).

One alternative I'm considering is seeding legit torrents based on a RSS feed. But for that I need suggestions on what RSS feed to use. The RSS should optimally be regularly and reliably updated with files that at the moment need extra seeding. But I'm open to other alternatives if they're evidently better.

Note: this question is more specific than [Charitable uses of upload bandwidth?](https://superuser.com/questions/11361/charitable-uses-of-upload-bandwidth?rq=1)

Comment: I can't see how this question would attract any different answers from http://superuser.com/questions/11361/charitable-uses-of-upload-bandwidth